# How to create a vector with logarithmically decreasing spacing in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, logarithm

I want to create a time vector, from 1e-7 to 1e-5 with a higher resolution (smaller spacing) at the end.

The standard `v = logspace(-7,-5)` creates a vector with logarithmically *increasing* spacing. If I switch the order of `a` and `b` (`logspace(-5,-7)`) and use `flip(v)` the spacing is still the same, just the order of the numbers change.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to specify an additional parameter besides the limits and the number of values: the base of the logarithm. This is equivalent to choosing where you sample the values on the logarithmic curve.

This code generates a sequence of logarithmically decreasing values in between your two limits:

```matlab
lims = [1e-7,1e-5];
N = 10;
e = 10; % we'll generate linear values from 1 to e

% Generate logarithmic sequence (we need to flip for decreasing intervals)
d = flip(exp(linspace(1, e, N)));

% Map the sequence to our limits
d = (d - d(1)) / (d(end) - d(1));
d = d * (lims(2) - lims(1)) + lims(1);
```

`d` is:

```
   1.0e-05 *

    0.0100    0.6359    0.8661    0.9508    0.9820    0.9935    0.9977    0.9992    0.9998    1.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could mirror the vector onto the half plane x<0 by multiplication with -1. Then the spacing is largest for the smaller numbers and decreasing, but v is in the interval -10^-5 to -10^-7.

Move v to the desired interval by adding 10^-5+10^-7.

Use the flip function so that v is ordered with the smallest element first and increasing.

```
v = logspace(-7,-5);
v = 1E-7+1E-5-v;
v = flip(v);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?